# getting RuntimeException error while uploading image

Tags: java, android

I am uploading an image. When I run application from eclipse on my device it runs fine and uploads file perfectly fine. When I close app and start it from device menu and then when I try to upload image it gives me RuntimeException error. I have no idea whats going on. Help please

here is my code

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
ImageView ivUserImage;
Button bUpload;
Intent i;
int CameraResult = 0;
Bitmap bmp;
public String globalUID;
UserFunctions userFunctions;
String photoName;
InputStream is;
String largeImagePath;

int serverResponseCode = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
    openCamera();
}

private void openCamera() {
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //set image taken from camera on ImageView
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image
         String[] largeFileProjection = {
                 MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                 MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
         };

         String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
         Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);

         try {
             myCursor.moveToFirst();
             //This will actually give you the file path location of the image.
             largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));

             File f = new File("" + largeImagePath);

             photoName = f.getName();

             bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     new Upload().execute(largeImagePath, globalUID, photoName);
                 }

             });

         } finally {
             myCursor.close();
         }
    }
}
public class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String success = "false";
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(largeImagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imageName", photoName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", globalUID));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.info/android/fileupload.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(response != null) {
                success = "true";
            }
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return success;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String f) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

here is my logcat

```
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:573)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:384)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:412)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at com.zafar.login.Camera$Upload.doInBackground(Camera.java:122)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at com.zafar.login.Camera$Upload.doInBackground(Camera.java:1)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-23 14:47:50.830: E/AndroidRuntime(7069):     ... 4 more
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069): Activity com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a67df0 that was originally added here
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a67df0 that was originally added here
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:266)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:174)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at com.zafar.login.Camera$Upload.onPreExecute(Camera.java:115)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at com.zafar.login.Camera$1.onClick(Camera.java:100)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-23 14:47:56.280: E/WindowManager(7069):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget, search this will get a lot of help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966 will help you

Comment: @DheereshSingh and duffy56 How can I use that method on that link in my code. I am trying that but that one is used for files not for images. Could you modify my code with that method? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

First of all with the help of @DheereshSingh and @duffy356 comments. I found it solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400754/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-on-bitmap).