# Out Of Memory Exception after sharing image to app multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-studio, share

I have an app which I share images to. Usually it works just fine, but after 5 or 6 shares the app crashes when I try and share another image to it and the error im getting is the OutOfMemory Exception. After the crash the sharing works just fine for about 5-6 shares, and again crashing.
My question is how to correct this. 
Here is the Error:

```
09-14 18:28:59.290 2224-2224/com.example.user.aitzik4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:378)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:934)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:660)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:393)
    at com.example.user.aitzik4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my MainActivity:

https://pastebin.com/x0bDdDLe

The function which recives the images is called `handleSendImage()`.

Thank you!

Comment: Post code here rather than links.  And have you used the heap profiler to find whats leaking yet?  Its probably one of your activities.

Comment: The code, but not _all_ the code. Preferably something like a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `handleSendImage` method:

You need to scale down the images to avoid `outOfMemory` Exceptions. Your images are prolly too large and takes a whole lot of memory.

To scale down your images you can check this.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java#load-bitmap

Or simply just use Picasso Library

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Using high-res image will cause memory issue if not handled properly.

You can refer some of below posts to handle images in Android:

[java.lang.outofmemoryerror bitmap size exceeds vm budget on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400754/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-on-bitmap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

[android Image view out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250300/android-image-view-out-of-memory-error)

Quick work-around: Set `largeHeap="true"` in your `manifest`. But this is not fool-proof.

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

> android:largeHeap="true"

```
 <application
    android:name="com.xxx.xx"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        -----

  </application>
```

Comment: You should add a disclaimer that `largeHeap="true"` is a bad idea most of the time, this is only a last resort answer.