# Rotate Image in and Update Mediastore

Tags: android, rotation, mediastore

I have a gallery app that needs to allow the user to rotate an image. I have attempted to do this in a few different ways.

I tried updating MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION, but this had no effect.

I attempted to rotate a bitmap and insert it via MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() but this creates a new image with new values for DATE_ADDED, DESCRIPTION, etc. Not acceptable.

This is a simple task. What is the correct method?

Comment: Basically, You want to  rotate your Image automatically when your Image activity start???

Comment: OR Rotated Image saved in your device storage??

Comment: saved in device storage, specifically the mediastore external

Comment: Refer this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444133/how-to-save-image-bitmap-after-rotation