# No exif data for images using front facing camera using cwac-library

Tags: android, cwac-camera

I have built my custom camera app using cwac-library. I am trying to access exif data for the images captured using **front camera**, but exif tags like TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, TAG_MAKE, TAG_MODEL.. is returning null. Only tag working is TAG_DATETIME. This only happens for the pictures taken using **front camera**, every tag is perfectly returning values for the images taken using **rear camera**

Any thing I am missing while using front-camera?

Including Codes

> **Custom Camera Fragment Class**

```
   public class CustomCameraFragment extends CameraFragment {
      static CustomCameraFragment newInstance() {
       return new CustomCameraFragment();
      }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    SimpleCameraHost.Builder builder = new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new CustomCameraHost(getActivity()));
    builder.useFullBleedPreview(true);
    builder.useFrontFacingCamera(true);
    builder.mirrorFFC(true);
    setHost(builder.build());
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View cameraView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
    FrameLayout cameraPreview = (FrameLayout)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    ((ViewGroup)cameraPreview).addView(cameraView);
    return fragmentView;
  }
}
```

> **Custom Camera Host Class**

```
public class CustomCameraHost extends SimpleCameraHost {
      public CustomCameraHost(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
      }

      @Override
      public Parameters adjustPictureParameters(PictureTransaction xact, Parameters parameters) {
        Location location = LocationUtils.getLastKnownLocation();
        parameters.setGpsLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        parameters.setGpsLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        parameters.setGpsProcessingMethod(location.getProvider().toUpperCase());
        if (location.hasAltitude()) {
         parameters.setGpsAltitude(location.getAltitude());
        } else {
         parameters.setGpsAltitude(0);
        }
        if (location.getTime() != 0) {
        // Location.getTime() is UTC in milliseconds. Gps-timestamp is UTC in seconds.
        long utcTimeSeconds = location.getTime() / 1000;
        parameters.setGpsTimestamp(utcTimeSeconds);
      }
      return super.adjustPictureParameters(xact, parameters);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show us your codes .

Comment: @Raptor edited my question and included codes

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245556/exif-orientation-tag-value-always-0-for-image-taken-with-portrait-camera-app-and Seems it's a known bug.

Comment: Exif data's are lost when **mirrorFFC** is enabled. With **mirrorFFC** disabled, all supported tags are returning proper value for the images taken using **Front Camera**. Is there anyway to resolve this issue?